# Cargar TClientDataSet al iniciar formulario

Tags: delphi

Hola tengo un formulario de pedido de una distribuidora, el mismo tiene el cliente asociado, el detalle de productos del pedido, y el ID del pedido en un DBEDit. La idea inicial del formulario es que al crearlo (abrirlo desde el principal) aparezca el ultimo ID creado de pedido, osea el ultimo cargado.

Tengo en el evento OnCreate lo siguiente:

```
procedure TPEDIDO.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
 idpedido: Integer;

begin

 Position := poScreenCenter;
 // obtengo el pedido actual

 if DBEdit1.Text <> '' then
 begin
    
    // hago la consulta con este id y obtengo el detalle
    idpedido := StrToInt(DBEdit1.Text);
    DataModule1.qdetpedido.Close;
    DataModule1.qdetpedido.ParamByName('idp').AsInteger := idpedido;
    DataModule1.qdetpedido.ExecSQL();

  end;
   // edito el dataset de cliente para mostrar el nombre en el dbedit
   DataModule1.cdscp.Edit;
   DataModule1.cdscpIdCliente.AsInteger :=
   DataModule1.cdspedidosIdCliente.AsInteger;
   DataModule1.cdsproductos.First;
   // agrego los codigos de articulos a las columnas
   while not DataModule1.cdsproductos.eof do
     begin
       PEDIDO.gpedidotemp.Columns[2].PickList.Add
      (DataModule1.cdsproductosCodigo.AsString);

       PEDIDO.gpedidotemp.Columns[3].PickList.Add
      (DataModule1.cdslistasNombre.AsString);

      DataModule1.cdsproductos.Next;
     end;
end;
```

Como veran "qdetpedido" es un TSQLQuery (trabajo con MySQL) que tiene un parametro "idp" que es el idpedido para traer los datos del mismo. La consulta es la siguiente:

```
 select * from detallepedido where detallepedido.Idpedido=:idp;
```

Tengo un DBEdit para mostrar el nombre del cliente asociado , lo que intento es posicionar el cursor del DataSet para que aparezca el nombre pero tampoco funciona.

Y por ultimo cargo en la grilla "gpedidotemp" los codigos alfanumericos en forma de combo, pero no aparecen los detalles.

Comment: ¿Cuándo hablas de "cargar el pedido", hablas de crear un pedido nuevo con la misma información o simplemente de mostrar el último pedido que se ha guardado en la base de datos? ¿Utilizas Providers en tu aplicación?

Comment: Con cargar el pedido me refiero a cargar el ultimo que se ha guardado en la base de datos. Y si los TClientDataSets estan conectados a providers.

Comment: ¿Tienes una tabla de encabezado y una de detalle de pedido? ¿Tenes una relación maestro/detalle entre encabezado y detalle de pedido en Delphi?

Comment: En la base de datos tengo la tabla pedido y la de detallepedido. Ahora bien, los dataset estan separados. No tengo relacion maestro detalle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el código actual de tu pregunta, técnicamente no estás mostrando los registros que están en la base de datos, sino creando registros nuevos en el *ClientDataSet* de detalle del pedido. Si llamas al método `ApplyUpdates`, estos registros se agregarán a lo que existe en la base de datos.

Dado que utilizas un *Provider* para conectar el *SQLQuery* al *ClientDataSet*, para mostrar los registros que están en la base de datos, puedes pasar el parámetro del *id* del pedido utilizando dicho *provider*.

Finalmente, yo haría un método que recupere un pedido completo de la base de datos, de manera que nos aseguramos que siempre estarán *sincronizados* los *DataSets* que lo representan en memoria, algo como:

```
procedure TdmPedido.AbrirPedido(idPedido: Integer);
begin
  cdsPedido.Close;
  cdsDetallePedido.Close;
  cdsPedido.FetchParams;
  cdsDetallePedido.FetchParams;

  cdsPedido.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idPedido;
  cdsPedido.Open;
  cdsDetallePedido.Params.ParamByName('idp').Value := idPedido;
  cdsDetallePedido.Open;
end;
```

Y luego invocaría ese método desde el formulario, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TfrmPedido.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Edit1.Text <> '' then
    dmPedido.AbrirPedido(StrToInt(Edit1.Text));
  //otras tareas de inicialización del formulario...
end;
```

Comment: Gracias @jachguate! Sos un gran maestro. Funciono perfecto! Saludos desde Argentina